# CefSharp browser refreshes after it loses its parent

Tags: cefsharp

So, I have a ChromiumBrowser inside a Windows Form in VB.net.
That form is atached to the "main" parent of the application. When the From is stripped from its parent, it becomes undocked and can be moved outside of the main form. But the moment the parent is removed, the browser is refreshed and I don't want it to do that.
I implemented IResourceHandler to check what method is being called but now the browser won't work because it doesn't know how to handle anything.
Is there a specific handler where I can intercept that call?
Any info is appreciated.

EDIT: Ok, so after reading @amaitland 's comment I changed the URL that I was using to instead load google, and after undocking the form it looks like it is refreshing, but manages to keep the page where it was. 
The weird thing is, the default browser does not behave like this.

Comment: Is the control handle being recreated? It's unlikely that the browser is refreshing, more likely a new instance is being created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is refreshing, because it just goes back to the main page. For Example. While docked you browse to >main>menu>items
But if you undock it will go back to >main
Like if you do a full refresh on a page.

Comment: More likely the handle is being recreated which currently isn't supported. You should add some debugging to be sure rather than assume